# slim black object on 1st generation macbook air case

Tags: macbook-pro

This is just a curiosity: what is that slim black part (see picture) in the Apple Macbook Air 1,1 (Early 2008) case?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the Apple's user manual it is the Infrared Receiver.

http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/0/MA394/en_US/MacBook_Air_Users_Guide.pdf

The "Sleep Indicator Light" is next to it on the left.

The MacBook beneath it has the same configuration.

Comment: This is correct.  It's only real use was with the Apple remote, for controlling iTunes and FrontRow.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me correctly it is the power light.